# ssl only root is able to verify the first certificate

Tags: 16.04, ssl

In my Ubuntu 16.04 I could successfully import the root CA, but the first certificate can be verified by root only.

Is it possible to let other users to verify the root CA?

How I did it:  I first copied the .crt file to the `/usr/share/ca-certificates`, then:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

The `/usr/share/ca-certificates-ca.crt` has permission mode 754 (-rwxr-xr--). My `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` has permission mode 644 (-rw-r--r--)

openssl s_client verification by non-root still results in:

```
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

Any further ideas what could cause the problem?
After that I was able to verify the first certificate, but only as root.

How can I let other users verify it?

Comment: Did you try and put it in `/etc/ssl/certs` direcyly?  You *may* need to put things there, some things refer to `/etc/ssl/certs` directly rather than using `/usr/share/ca-certificates/`.

Answer (score 0):

If only root can use the new certificate, it might be that you didn't give read permissions to the new certificate file.

You can check that by running `ls -lsa /usr/share/ca-certificates/new-cert-name.crt` and see if other has `read permission`

if not, you can add `read permission` to the  certificate using

```
sudo chmod +r /usr/share/ca-certificates/new-cert-name.crt
```

> Note: change the name of the certificate file name to the one you are using

You should also make sure that you can access `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` , e.g. check that you can read its data as non-root user:

```
cat /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

check its permissions using

```
ls -lsa /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Grant read permission if missing using:

```
sudo chmod +r /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```